# Procedure SQL (executada a cada segundo)

Tags: mysql, sql

Alguém pode me explicar como vai funcionar esse comando mysql?

```
 SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS n_linha , m.* FROM
    (SELECT b.user_id as prox_user_id, t.auctionID, t.productID, t.auc_due_price+t.auc_plus_price AS prox_valor, t.auc_due_time, b.id as id_lance, t.auc_plus_time, t.auc_plus_price
    FROM bidbutler b
    inner join c_cron_tempo t on b.auc_id = t.auctionID
    where b.butler_status = 0 and (b.butler_bid-b.used_bids)>0
      and t.auc_due_time < GREATEST(LEAST(TRUNCATE(15 * RAND(),0),15),3)
    Order by b.auc_id, RAND()) m,(SELECT @row :=0) r;
```

Principalmente a parte dos RAND ali, não consegui entender.

Eu sei que ele executa em vários valores do RAND, como eu poderia fazer também para ele executar em um valor definido por mim sem o RAND?

Answer (score 3):

- A [função `RAND()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) retorna um `float` de 0 a 1.
  (exemplo: `0.47806898642151524`. Multiplicado por 15: `7.171034796322728`)
- A [função `TRUNCATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) corta um `float` por um número de casas 
  decimais passado no segundo parâmetro. (exemplo para `TRUNCATE(7.171034796322728, 0)`: `7`, pois deixa zero casas decimais)
- A [função `LEAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) retorna o *menor* de dois números. (exemplo para `LEAST(7,15)`: `7`)
- A [função `GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) retorna o *maior* de dois números. (exemplo para `GREATEST(7,3)`: `7`)

Portanto, o comando:

```
select GREATEST(LEAST(TRUNCATE(15 * RAND(),0),15),3)
```

Retornará um *número aleatório entre 3 e 15*.

Usando o mesmo raciocínio para alterar o range para, por exemplo, entre 1 e 5, multiplique o resultado de `RAND()` por 5, defina o teto em `LEAST()` como 5 e o mínimo em `GREATEST()` como 1:

```
select GREATEST(LEAST(TRUNCATE(5 * RAND(),0),5),1);
```

(Segue SQL Fiddle exemplificando o uso de cada função, bem como execuções seguidas do comando acima para demonstrar o grau de aleatoriedade obtido: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340e01/69)

A sua query completa utiliza esse método para verificar se o campo `auc_due_time` é menor do que um número qualquer entre 3 e 15.

Se você quer fixar o número, retire todo esse bloco e substitua direto pelo número que quer definir, por exemplo *10*:

```
...
and t.auc_due_time < 10
...
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações. Como seria para definir um número aleatório entre 1 e 5?

Comment: O por que tem aquele 15 * antes?

Comment: E o zero por que ta ali no meio?

Comment: @Wendler editei a resposta para responder a essas perguntas. Para mudar o range é só mudar a multiplicação e os limites em `LEAST()` e `GREATEST() `. O `15 * RAND()` é uma multiplicação necessária porque o resultado de `RAND()` retorna sempre um número menor ou igual a 1. O zero é o segundo parâmetro passado para o `TRUNCATE()`, que é número de casas decimais a manter do resultado da multiplicação. No caso é nenhuma casa decimal porque a query quer um número inteiro entre 3 e 15, não uma fração.